# npm not installing packages when i want to

Tags: npm, installation, npm-install

Most of the times when I try to install a package, I get this message:

*npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 117 while parsing '{

npm ERR!   "requires": true,

npm ERR!   "lockfileVersion'*

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your **package.json** must be of **valid json syntax**. If you're sure nothing is wrong with it , then it could be your **package-lock.json** file that is corrupted.delete it and run npm install again.

Comment: @voom did you figure it out?

Comment: No @Helix112, I deleted my package-lock.json and ran npm install but it came up with another error message